# How to remove index.php

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameters, get

Hello  I try to replaca url  www.orif-agent.ro/index.php?page=contact in orif-agent.ro/contact

for home page (index.php) i used this

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

but i don't know how to hide parameters for get method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=([^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%2/? [L,R=301]
```